# Is there a method for finding two irrational numbers that multiply together to form a rational number

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I know multiplying $x*\frac{1}{x}$ gives us the rational number 1 as long as x is nonzero. I also know the square of rational numbers multiplied by itself gives us a rational number. Are these the only way of finding irrational numbers that multiply to a rational one? What about numbers $a$ and $b$ where $b\ne\frac{1}{a}$? Do such numbers exist?

Comment: $x\cdot\dfrac2x$, $x\cdot\dfrac3{2x}$,$\ldots$?

Comment: If $xy=r$  then (if $x\neq 0$) $y=\frac rx$, so...

Comment: $\sqrt{24} \cdot \sqrt{54}$, $(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)$ ...

Comment: $\frac qx$, for any irrational $x$ and rational $q$, has the property that $x\cdot\frac qx$ is rational. Moreover, $\frac qx$ must be irrational whenever $q\neq0$.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways. consider...... Let $r$ but *any* non-zero rational number possible, any at all (except 0).  And let $w$ but *any* irrational number possible, any at all.  Then $v=\frac rw$ is an irrational number (unless $r=0$; then $v =0$ but if $r$ is *anything* else then $v=\frac rw$ is irrational).  And so..... $v \cdot w = r$.  And you have it.  Two irrationals that multiplied together form a rational.... yeah, I know it feels like cheating "but we constructed it deliberately so it would work". But... if you think of it if $wv=r$ it *must* be $w=\frac rv$.

Comment: All perfect powers when the roots applied to the 2 divisors not giving integers, e.g.: $\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{8}$.

Comment: "What about numbers a and b where b≠1a? Do such numbers exist?"  Sure.  $b = \frac ra$ where $r\ne 0$ is rational.  But no *other* exist and *all* are of this type even if you didn't *find* them that way.  For example $\sqrt{54}\sqrt {6}= 18$ and we didn't *try* to do "Let $b = \frac {18}{\sqrt {54}}$" to find it. But the result *does* (and *must*) hold that $\sqrt 6$ *does* equal $\frac {18}{\sqrt{54}}$. [FWIW the method I *did* use to find it was Let $a=\sqrt{m^{odd}n^{odd}}$ and $b = \sqrt{m^{otherodd}n^{otherodd}}=\sqrt{m^{even}n^{even}}=a^{something}b^{something}$.]

Comment: Arrgh... typo in last comment.  The method used was: Let $a=\sqrt{m^{odd}n^{odd}}$ and $b = \sqrt{m^{otherodd}n^{otherodd}}$ so $ab = \sqrt{m^{even}n^{even}}=a^{something}b^{something}$

Answer (score 2):

If you want $wv = r$ where $w,v$ are irrational and $r$ is rational, that must mean that $w =\frac rv$ (since $v$ is irrational it *isn't* $0$ so we don't have to worry about that)

So to find any pair you want just pick any arbitrary rational number (so long as it is not zero; as $w \ne 0$ and $v\ne 0$ then $wv \ne 0$; but that is the *only* restriction; we can pick any other rational at all),  and pick any arbitrary irrational $v$.  Then let $w = \frac rv$.  As $v$ is irrational and $r$ is non-zero rational we will have $w = \frac rv$ be irrational.

And we have, voila  $wv = \frac rv \cdot v = r$.

Comment: But David Laczko, I was talking about bringing out a stringed instrument and playing a few bars!  What did *you* think I meant?

Comment: It didn't came to my mind...